# How would I set section numbering to a specific format - e. g. 1 (first level) -> 1. (second level) -> 1.1. (third level) in Lyx?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, lyx

I am creating a document for school and I am required to follow a specific format for numbering - that is: "1", then "1.", then "1.1." and so on. I am a Latex and Lyx beginner and haven't found a way to do this in this specific way (or in a simple enough way that I could follow). Should I use some package? Is there some preamble thing for this? Or would I have to do this manually?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Edit 1: Posting a MWE. I am using the article document class with manually changed section numbering to start from 0.
Code:

```latex
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\setcounter{section}{-1}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{John Doe}
\maketitle

\section{Preface}

\section{Characteristics}

\section{Division}

\subsection{Group A}

\subsubsection{A}

\subsubsection{B}

\paragraph{B1}

\section{Conclusion}
\end{document}
```

Screenshot from Lyx:
[image: Lyx code screenshot]

Comment: This highly depends on the documentclass you are using. Can you provide a minimal working example (MWE) such that we can help you there directly with the code?

Comment: I thought it would have something to do with documentclass, but I don't really know their differences. I will edit to post a MWE now but I will have to go to sleep afterwards.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Thank you, after diving in it seems I will have to post here more often than anticipated. Once again, thanks for the answer and your help overall!

Answer (score 1):

A brute-force solution is to run

```
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection\arabic{subsubsection}.}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\thesubsubsection\arabic{paragraph}.}
```

Unfortunately, this will create unwanted issues if you ever need to cross-reference subsection-, subsubsection-, and paragraph-level units. I therefore suggest you take the following, indirect or "circumspect" approach. I picked up this approach up some years ago, while reading the book "The LaTeX Companion" (2nd ed.).

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc} %% Are you absolutely sure about 'latin9'?!
\usepackage{babel}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % default is '3'
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

%% Brute-force method:
%\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}.}
%\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection\arabic{subsubsection}.}
%\renewcommand\theparagraph{\thesubsubsection\arabic{paragraph}.}

%% Circumspect method:
\makeatletter
% the next 4 lines are straight from "The LaTeX Companion", 2nd ed.
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}   % default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname} % enable individual control
}

\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}
\newcommand{\subsection@cntformat}{\thesubsection.\quad}
\newcommand{\subsubsection@cntformat}{\thesubsubsection.\quad}
\newcommand{\paragraph@cntformat}{\theparagraph.\quad}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{-1}
\section{Preface}
\section{Characteristics}
\section{Division}

\subsection{Group A}

\subsubsection{A} \label{sec:A}
\subsubsection{B} \label{sec:B}

\paragraph{B1} \label{sec:B1}

\section{Conclusion}

Cross-references to subsubsections \ref{sec:A} and \ref{sec:B} 
and to parapraph \ref{sec:B1}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted, thank you. I am still a beginner though, and I would like to be able to better understand/ eventually make these kinds of things myself. I found some documentation, tutorials... but none of it is really unified. Would you recommend any specific place/ textbook I should start to improve my knowledge?
 
(About the 'latin9', I am not sure at all, I don't really understand the settings, Lyx put that in the source code. Should I not use 'inputenc' at all?)

Comment: @MegaTortoise - Glad to learn that my answer was useful. :-) About general learning resources for TeX: Please see the posting [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/5001) By now, the default input encoding for LaTeX has been UTF8 for several years, and I believe that lyx's built-in editor also employs UTF8 input encoding. Since `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is the default, the statement is redundant and may as well be omitted.